# Watin: is there a way to call ImageByTitle from a table cell?

Tags: c#, .net, automated-tests, watin

I have two clickable images in a table cell and need to click on them as part of a watin test run. The images have no IDs (nothing I can do about it). The images repeat every row with the same title.

I can call the image in the first row by using *ImageByTitle("imageTitle").click()*, but when I get to a cell in any other row I can't use that.

Is there a way to use ImageByTitle in a TableCell object, or is there another solution to this that I'm just not seeing?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you cycle through table cells?

Comment: Thanks @Gabber. I ended up calling the images container in the cell, and iterated through them while looking at each image's title (the only thing I had to go by) to pick the one i needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there's no OOTB function to find images by title in a table cell, there is an option to get a collection of all the images in the given cell.

Once I had the collection, I iterated through the images by looking at each image title, and picked the one I needed to click on.

Thanks :)